# How to solve Update-Database issue when switching branch?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

I have one entity which has a column as `int` in Branch **A**. Now I switch to a different Branch **B**. There I create a migration and change column to `varchar` and run `Update-Database`. Now If I switch to Branch **A** again. If I see in the code the column datatype is `int`, but in the database, its datatype is `varchar`. But I want its datatype to be `int`. I can not even remove this migration from Branch **A** because it was created in Branch **B**.I can see only one way to solve this issue is to delete the database and run `Update-Database`, But I will lose all data by doing this. Is there any better way to solve this issue.

I'm using entity framework core 2.0.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two options:

1. Use a different database for each branch (probably the best idea, IMHO)
2. Before switching back to branch **A**, un-apply the migration from the database with `Update-Database name-of-previous-migration`

For example, let's assume you have the following migrations:

- `20180214094058_Initial.cs`
- `20180216100541_FirstMigration.cs`
- `20180218185111_MigrationBranchB.cs`

You can un-apply `MigrationBranchB` with `Update-Database FirstMigration` (this will call the `Down` method of `MigrationBranchB`).

Relevant [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#reverting-a-migration):

> **Reverting a migration**
>
> If you already applied a migration (or several migrations) to the database but need to revert it, you can use the same command to apply migrations, but specify the name of the migration you want to roll back to.
>
> `Update-Database LastGoodMigration`

Comment: But I want to apply these changes ultimately to the actual database with the existing data.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you applied a migration in branch B that was a mistake (you want an int), you want to preserve the data in the column, but as int instead of `varchar`?

Comment: Let's suppose Branch A is the main branch and I have a feature branch B. I will point to the same DB.

Comment: Migration was intentional

Comment: So you can merge branch B into branch A?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to merge B into A

Comment: Then if you merge branch B into branch A, your database will match your code, so I'm still unsure what your issue is.

Comment: yes, My code is matching, But at this stage, I'm not merging my code to the main branch, I will do it later.

Comment: this is the case like if you are working on multiple branches parallel

Comment: This should be part of your process anyways. When working in a branch and you add migrations. When you're ready to commit, first rollback to the state before you started work, removing all accumulated migrations. Then generate a new migration to encompass all database changes in the branch. Then commit. If you don't apply this new migration to your database, then it will already be in a state ready to switch to a new branch. Each time you switch branches, you update your database to apply in migrations in that branch before starting work. Rinse and repeat.